# 'Range not found' when trying to input value into first empty cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google Script/Spreadsheet issue, here.

Am trying to copy data from one cell and put it into the first empty cell in column E. When I perform the following, I get 'Range not found' on line 15:

```
function operationsLag() {
  var report = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var reportValues = report.getDataRange().getValues();
  var lastRow = getFirstEmptyRow('E');
var income = "Income";

for (var i = 0; i < reportValues.length; i++) {
    var row = reportValues[i];
    if (row[0] == income) {
      report.getRange(lastRow).setValue(row[1]);
}
}
}

  function getFirstEmptyRow(columnLetter) {
  var rangeA1 = columnLetter + ':' + columnLetter;
  var report = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var column = report.getRange(rangeA1);
  var values = column.getValues();
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }
  return (ct+1);
}
```

I've tried replacing `report.getRange(lastRow).setValue(row[1]);` with something like `report.getRange('E5').setValue(row[1]);` and it works fine, so there must be something wrong with my find empty cell/row function.

Can anybody help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue:

The [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) function with one argument accepts a `string` and that is the reference cell notation e.g. `E5` and this is why `getRange('E5')` works correctly.

On the other hand `lastRow` is not an `a1Notation` but a single `integer` number. The script can't find which cell you are referring to from something like that `getRange(2)` because that can be any column (if `2` is assumed to be a row number).

### Solution:

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to construct the `a1Notation` based on `lastRow`.

**Replace:**

```
report.getRange(lastRow).setValue(row[1]);
```

**With:**

```
report.getRange(`E${lastRow}`).setValue(row[1]);
```

**or** use the [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) version where `5` is column `E` (the `5th` column).

```
report.getRange(lastRow,5).setValue(row[1]);
```

Comment: Mario, this is fantastic, and not only that allows me to do even more. Thanks so much,